# Generate A list View interface using JSOM (SharePoint 2013, SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, jsom, view, napa

I'm querying multiple lists from all the sites in the site collection, using JSOM/REST

Is it possible to create a List view webpart with the results of the query ?

I know this is possible using SharePoint Designer or Farm solutions and sandboxed solutions, but This options are not available due reasons in our organization and SP online.

Is it possible to display the extracted items as a list view web part with using the JSOM or Napa (SharePoint Online only)?

Comment: Napa is dead: https://www.napacloudapp.com/

Comment: You have to create all HTML for the JSOM/REST data you receive yourself.

Comment: I wanted to create something that had the same interface as C# visual web part controls (headers, filters, sorting) but it seems it will require a lot of HTML and CSS, or might not even be possible

Comment: It is possible.. just a shitload of work. Modern approach is SharePoint Framework (SPFx) ... but even that won't get you any of the HTML5 scaffolding.. you have to add Fabric (still some issues in combo with SPFx) Microsoft is all about "_Sharing is caring_".. but they do **not** share the code they use for their Modern Experience ListViews